# What is the difference between an Ontology and Knowledge Representation (KR)?

Tags: knowledge-representation, definitions

From my understanding an Ontology is a description of how a real object can be understood or represented (such as *a chair* being *a collection of atoms*, *a piece of furniture* part of a larger collection of other furniture belonging in a room or perhaps *a description of how the components of a chair are related to each other*).

On the other hand I think KR is the digital representation of an Ontology (such as a *struct*, *class*, *graph*, *tree* or other model).

I am quite certain that I am wrong and I am finding it hard to answer this question on my own.

Could someone clarify the difference for me? Thank you.

Comment: I have also posted this question on [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24920/what-is-the-difference-between-ontology-and-knowledge-representation-kr) where an answer has been provided. Please keep this open in case somebody else knows the answer to this question.